# How do I send out notification messages to skype groups using the azure bot framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype, azure-bot-service, skypedeveloper

I am new to the Azure Bot Framework and I am trying to do something that I think is quite simple.

I have a Node application that a few times a day needs to send notifications to various skype groups. I have been using [skype-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skype-http) for a while, but it is unreliable and not officially supported by Microsoft. So, I am looking to rebuild the notification system using azure services.

It seems like I should be creating an [Azure Bot Function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/04/22/azure-bot-function/), but the Bot Functions use the V3 API, which is deprecated.

It looks like [Web App Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) are now the recommended option to create bots, but they seem to be solving a slightly different problem. But going this route, it looks like I still need to set up an Azure Function as well as storage. So, it seems vastly more complex than my current implementation.

My question is: Should I be using a Bot Function, a Web App Bot, or something else entirely to send notifications to multiple chat groups?

---

**EDIT:** To be clear, I am looking for an officially supported solution. skype-http regularly breaks for us due to API changes, and the other node-based skype libraries are similarly brittle.

Or, please let me know if there is no Microsoft-supported solution, then at least I know I will be stuck using private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Azure Functions as your platform, instead. Azure Functions would allow you to make the API calls you need. Additionally, you can set it to run via a trigger (timer or http request).

Instead of skype-http, check out sky-web-plus (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sky-web-plus). It's basically a port of several other packages already out there, but is getting regular love from its developer (so, hopefully stable and up-to-date) and *appears* to do what you need. As the developer is active, you can reach out to him/her with any specific questions.

Azure Bot Framework would not be a good fit for this purpose, alone.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like there is no official Microsoft-supported way of doing what we want to. We looked at skyweb as well, but it is using internal skype REST calls, just like skype-http. My concern is that at any moment, Microsoft can change its internal APIs and all of our apps that rely on them will be broken. I'll wait a bit longer to hear from any of the Azure people directly, but otherwise I think your answer is correct.